# Corda transaction basic questions

Tags: corda

I have some basic questions about Corda's transaction functionality:

1. For transactions between alice & bob, does bob have to manually sign/verify the transaction or does bob's node automatically sign for it?
2. If I am transacting with a bank that is on your platform, like HSBC, and I withdraw funds, would the funds go directly into my HSBC bank account?
3. From what I've learnt so far, is that Corda's notary service acts as a TTP; however, what if I don't trust Corda's notary service and want a consensus mechanism that isn't reliant on any authority?

Answer (score 2):

1. Nodes don't have to sign transactions manually, signing happens in the context of the flows written in the CordDapp, the CorDapps are installed in the node.
2. That would depend on the scope of the implementation. If the central bank is issuing the currency on Corda (something like CBDC), then with the new account functionality, yes that is a possibility.
3. A notary is just a general Corda node with some extra responsibility for preventing double-spending. You cannot really remove the notary altogether, but yes the consensus in notary cluster is pluggable. You could choose a different consensus algorith. Refer here for more details: https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-notaries.html#consensus-algorithms

Comment: Based on your responses:
1. How does the cordapp sign for bobs transaction with bobs private key? - Doesn't bob need to inspect and verify it?
2. If I am a business and decide to try out corda, what is the default currency?

Comment: Signing can be done using the `SignTransactionFlow` in the responding flow. However the trnx would be signed only of the contract verifies succeddfully. In cases where additional inspection is required, you could override the checkTransaction method of SignTransactionFlow to add custom verification logic.

Comment: There is no default currency in Corda. You could utilize finance module or TokenSDK to create one though

Comment: I am alice, and all i want to do is send bob 10 coins, so I send a signed tx to bob, and somehow bob needs to sign for it and send it back, please can you clarify who is signing bobs transaction? If it is bob, how does he go about signing the tx?

Comment: The signing is done by bob's node, after verifying that the transaction in contractually valid and any additional validation(if imposed). This happens in the responder flow when the transaction is sent to bob's node for verification and signing.